# In Javascript, how do I check if an array has duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

How do I check if an array has duplicate values?

If some elements in the array are the same, then return true. Otherwise, return false.

```
['hello','goodbye','hey'] //return false because no duplicates exist
['hello','goodbye','hello'] // return true because duplicates exist
```

Notice I don't care about finding the duplication, only want Boolean result whether arrays contains duplications.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array/840808#840808

Comment: I don't want a list of duplicates removed. I just want to know true or false if a list has duplicates in it.

Comment: The accepted answer for the *exact same question you asked* is your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array/840808#840808

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/gfJ28/

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. Since @user847495 simply wants to check if duplicates exists, the solution is faster/easier than what's needed to find all occurrences of duplicates. For example, you can do this: http://codr.io/v/bvzxhqm

Comment: using **underscore** ,simple technique `var test=['hello','goodbye','hello'] ; if ( test.length != _.unique(test).length ) { // some code  }`

Comment: **Not a duplicate of the marked question.** Please pay attention before marking questions as such.

Comment: Using underscore.js it is simple use   if(arrayA.length === _.uniq(ArrayA).length){ // do your work} --> if true all are distinct else not distinct

Answer (score 333, accepted):

If you have an ES2015 environment (as of this writing: io.js, IE11, Chrome, Firefox, WebKit nightly), then the following will work, and will be fast (viz. O(n)):

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
    return (new Set(array)).size !== array.length;
}
```

---

If you only need string values in the array, the following will work:

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (value in valuesSoFar) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar[value] = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

We use a "hash table" `valuesSoFar` whose keys are the values we've seen in the array so far. We do a lookup using `in` to see if that value has been spotted already; if so, we bail out of the loop and return `true`.

---

If you need a function that works for more than just string values, the following will work, but isn't as performant; it's O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n).

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (valuesSoFar.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
        valuesSoFar.push(value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The difference is simply that we use an array instead of a hash table for `valuesSoFar`, since JavaScript "hash tables" (i.e. objects) only have string keys. This means we lose the O(1) lookup time of `in`, instead getting an O(n) lookup time of `indexOf`.

Comment: About the first example you gave. Isn't the validation exactly the other way around? If your function is named `hasDuplicates`, then it should check if the set's size actually shrunk during the process of casting it, right? Therefore the boolean operator should be `!==` and not `===`

Comment: pls edit. I can't edit as I'm not changing more than 6 characters.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) IE11 does not the support the constructor used in the first example

Comment: Normal JS version returns `true` for the following array: `[1, '1']`

Comment: Thus "if you only need string values in the array" preceding the answer.

Comment: However it is not supported in IE11 as you mentioned.It would return size 0 .Try this in IE 11 `new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Comment: Solution 1 will not work for JSON objects check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#ExamplesSection

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to contribute with another solution that I ended up using. Just in case is useful for somebody: `[1,2,3,4,4].filter( (v, i, arr) => i !== arr.indexOf(v) )`. It will return an array with the repeated values (except the 1st occurrence).

Comment: ES2015 is a god.

Answer (score 20):

One line solutions with ES6

```js
const arr1 = ['hello','goodbye','hey'] 
const arr2 = ['hello','goodbye','hello'] 

const hasDuplicates = (arr) => arr.length !== new Set(arr).size;
console.log(hasDuplicates(arr1)) //return false because no duplicates exist
console.log(hasDuplicates(arr2)) //return true because duplicates exist
```

```js
const s1 = ['hello','goodbye','hey'].some((e, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) !== i)
const s2 = ['hello','goodbye','hello'].some((e, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(e) !== i);

console.log(s1) //return false because no duplicates exist
console.log(s2) //return true because duplicates exist
```

Comment: **FYI** - [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size) has a `.size` property, so you don't have to spread into an array to get `.length`

Answer (score 19):

You could use SET to remove duplicates and compare, If you copy the array into a set it will remove any duplicates. Then simply compare the length of the array to the size of the set.

```
function hasDuplicates(a) {

  const noDups = new Set(a);

  return a.length !== noDups.size;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach (also for object/array elements within the array<sup>**1**</sup>) could be<sup>**2**</sup>:

```
function chkDuplicates(arr,justCheck){
  var len = arr.length, tmp = {}, arrtmp = arr.slice(), dupes = [];
  arrtmp.sort();
  while(len--){
   var val = arrtmp[len];
   if (/nul|nan|infini/i.test(String(val))){
     val = String(val);
    }
    if (tmp[JSON.stringify(val)]){
       if (justCheck) {return true;}
       dupes.push(val);
    }
    tmp[JSON.stringify(val)] = true;
  }
  return justCheck ? false : dupes.length ? dupes : null;
}
//usages
chkDuplicates([1,2,3,4,5],true);                           //=> false
chkDuplicates([1,2,3,4,5,9,10,5,1,2],true);                //=> true
chkDuplicates([{a:1,b:2},1,2,3,4,{a:1,b:2},[1,2,3]],true); //=> true
chkDuplicates([null,1,2,3,4,{a:1,b:2},NaN],true);          //=> false
chkDuplicates([1,2,3,4,5,1,2]);                            //=> [1,2]
chkDuplicates([1,2,3,4,5]);                                //=> null
```

[See also...](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/uun3F/)

<sup>**1**</sup> needs a browser that supports JSON, or a [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) if not.
<sup>**2**</sup> **edit:** function can now be used for simple check or to return an array of duplicate values

Comment: Non-showstopper issues worth being aware of: 1) mutates the original array to be sorted; 2) does not differentiate between `null`, `NaN`, `Infinity`, `+Infinity`, and `-Infinity`; 3) objects are considered equal if they have the same own-properties, even if they have different prototypes.

Comment: @Domenic: yep, should've mentioned it. Edited to circumvent mutation of original array.

Comment: @Domenic: corrected for null/NaN/[+/-]Infinity, see edits.

Comment: @Domenic: Issue 3) is actually not a problem for me, because it is exactly what I want. I don't care about the prototype, just the values.

Answer (score 4):

You can take benefit of `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. if both indexes are not same, you have duplicate.

```
function containsDuplicates(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a.indexOf(a[i]) !== a.lastIndexOf(a[i])) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are dealing with simple values, you can use `array.some()` and `indexOf()`

for example let's say `vals` is `["b", "a", "a", "c"]`

```
const allUnique = !vals.some((v, i) => vals.indexOf(v) < i);
```

`some()` will return true if *any* expression returns true. Here we'll iterate values (from the index 0) and call the indexOf() that will return the index of the first occurrence of given item (or -1 if not in the array). If its id is smaller that the current one, there must be at least one same value before it. thus iteration 3 will return true as "a" (at index 2) is first found at index 1.

Answer (score 3):

is just simple, you can use the `Array.prototype.every` function

```js
function isUnique(arr) {
  const isAllUniqueItems = input.every((value, index, arr) => {
    return arr.indexOf(value) === index; //check if any duplicate value is in other index
  });

  return isAllUniqueItems;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if not using `Set`, since it uses the minimal amount of comparisons needed for a linear search approach + it also allows doing other checks at the same time, for example that no value in the array is `null`, with early exit as soon as a non-satisfying element is found (instead of first checking for duplicates and then check for other conditions after).

Answer (score 2):

**Why use this method:**

I think this is the best way to do it when dealing with multiple arrays and loops, this exaple is very simple but in some cases such when iterating with several loops and iterating through objects this is the most reliable and optimal way to do it.

**Explanation:**

In this example the array is iterated, element is the same as array[i] i being the position of the array that the loop is currently on, then the function checks the position in the read array which is initialized as empty, if the element is not in the read array it'll return -1 and it'll be pushed to the read array, else it'll return its position and won't be pushed, once all the element of array has been iterated the read array will be printed to console

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5]
let read = []

array.forEach(element => {
  if (read.indexOf(element) == -1) {
    read.push(element)
    console.log("This is the first time" + element + " appears in the array")
  } else {
    console.log(element + " is already in the array")
  }
})

console.log(read)
```

Answer (score 1):

One nice thing about solutions that use `Set` is `O(1)` performance on looking up existing items in a list, rather than having to loop back over it.

One nice thing about solutions that use `Some` is short-circuiting when the duplicate is found early, so you don't have to continue evaluating the rest of the array when the condition is already met.

One solution that combines both is to incrementally build a set, early terminate if the current element exists in the set, otherwise add it and move on to the next element.

```js
const hasDuplicates = (arr) => {
  let set = new Set()
  return arr.some(el => {
    if (set.has(el)) return true
    set.add(el)
  })
}

hasDuplicates(["a","b","b"]) // true
hasDuplicates(["a","b","c"]) // false
```

According to [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/51kypw9yd5/1), should preform pretty well for the varried use cases.  The set size approach is fastest with no dupes, and checking some + indexOf is fatest with a very early dupe, but this solution performs well in both scenarios, making it a good all-around implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.selectedExam = [];
    // example exam obj: {examId:1, name:'ExamName'}
    onExamSelect(exam: any) {
    if(!this.selectedExam.includes(exam?.name)){ 
      this.selectedExam.push(exam?.name);
    }}
```

In the above code, I have taken an array and on triggering a particular function (onExamSelect) we are checking duplicates and pushing unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, this is the best way to do it for an array of objects, checking *strict equality*. A `Set` cannot do this.

```
const answerTableRows = [
    { rk: "u", pk: "1", },
    { rk: "u", pk: "2", },
    { rk: "u", pk: "1", }, // get rid of this one
    { rk: "x", pk: "y" },
];
let uniqueAnswerTableRows = answerTableRows.filter((v, i, a) => {
    return a.findIndex(t => (t.rk === v.rk && t.pk === v.pk)) === i;
});
console.log(uniqueAnswerTableRows);
// [ { rk: 'u', pk: '1' }, { rk: 'u', pk: '2' }, { rk: 'x', pk: 'y' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/askavy/og2jzdt3/)

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
        var set = new Set();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (set.has(array[i])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                set.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    console.log(hasDuplicates(arr)); // Output: false
    
    var arrWithDuplicates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];
    console.log(hasDuplicates(arrWithDuplicates)); // Output: true
```

Answer (score -4):

```
function hasAllUniqueChars( s ){ 
    for(let c=0; c<s.length; c++){
        for(let d=c+1; d<s.length; d++){
            if((s[c]==s[d])){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be great if you'd explain your answer instead of only posting some code. Thanks!