# How to check if all values of a given array are unique

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function in JavaScript which would return a boolean after checking if all values of a given array are unique.
Examples

```
[1,2,3,4] true
[1,2,1,4] false, since the array has value '1' twice
```

Comment: Additionally `myArray.some((x, i, l) => l.indexOf(x) !== i)` is true iff `myArray` contains a duplicate.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376598/in-javascript-how-do-i-check-if-an-array-has-duplicate-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare length of your array and size of the Set which always contains uniq entries.

```js
const isUnique = (arrToTest) => 
  arrToTest.length === new Set(arrToTest).size

console.log(isUnique([1,1,2,3]));
console.log(isUnique([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: Of course, this won't work in all browsers (points dagger at internet exploder < 11)

Comment: @JaromandaX Of course if you check it in ie6 it also won't work, of course if you don't use babel or other transpilers and polyfills in your build chain in your day to day flow when using es6+, you are still likely to have problems with various old browser versions. This goes without saying, and half of the answers on stackoverflow that include es6+ answers imply that.

Comment: I know, I just like to remind people that internet exploder must die

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` and check for each sibling.

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
var array2 = [1,2,1,4];

function decorate(array) {
  array.uniques = function() {
    this.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i + 1] === this.length) return true;
      if (this[i] === this[i + 1]) return false;
    }
  }
}

decorate(array1);
decorate(array2);

console.log(array1.uniques());
console.log(array2.uniques());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom object

```
function checkUnique(array)
{ var i,obj={};
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  { if(obj[array[i]])
      return false;
    obj[array[i]]=true;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(checkUnique([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(checkUnique([1,2,1,4]));
```