# Best way to check if an existing array is having all distinct elements or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, distinct-values

Something like this:

```
let a = [2, 34, 'dafsd', null, {}];
let b = [null,  null] -or- ['same','same'] -or- [100, 100]
isDistinct(a) // => true
isDistinct(b) // => false
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: If you used a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you don't have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: Why should `isDistinct([{}, {}])` return `false`? It’s two distinct objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Javascript, how do I check if an array has duplicate values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376598/in-javascript-how-do-i-check-if-an-array-has-duplicate-values)

Comment: @Xufox sure they are different, my bad that I considered objects too, as that worth a separate question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the items and check the length of the array against the size of the set. If equal, then all elements are unique.

```js
let a = [2, 34, 'dafsd', null, {}];

console.log(a.length === new Set(a).size);
```

Comment: As an aside, just in case it's not clear to OP, Set definitely doesn't take into account the innards of objects. a.e. `new Set([ {a:1}, {a:1} ])` would return two objects. This is correct, but often confusing if you're newer to the language.