# Why does `arr.find()` return `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

In the below code `his._notifications` is an array of objects, each object contains the properties shown below.

What I am trying to do is to check if each object *not* passed to the function `func()` was pushed into the array or not?

So I am using `.find()` and I expect it returns `true` if the object was passed to the function or if it already exists in the array, and `false` otherwise.

But the below log statement prints `undefined`! Why `isExists` is undefined? And what is the recommended way to check if an item is duplicate or not in an array?

**code**:

```
func(noti)
const isExists = this._notifications.find((obj) =>
  obj.title === noti.safeTitle
  && obj.text === noti.safeText
  && obj.bannerTitle === noti.safeBannerTitle
  && obj.bannerText === noti.safeBannerText
  && obj.icon === noti.icon
  && obj.onClickCallback === noti.onClickCallback
  && obj.eNotificationType === noti.notificationType
  && obj.deleteable === noti.deletable
  && obj.withBanner === noti.withBanner
);
logger.info('[isNotificationExists] For the current notification: ', JSON.stringify(notification), ' isExists: ', isExists);
```

Comment: You may like to have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: @ArifKhan has nothing to do with object comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The **find()** method returns the value of the first element in the array
> that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
> returned.
>
> The **includes()** method determines whether an array includes a certain
> element, returning true or false as appropriate. It uses the
> sameValueZero algorithm to determine whether the given element is
> found.

[To check if an item is duplicated in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376598/in-javascript-how-do-i-check-if-an-array-has-duplicate-values)

```js
function hasDuplicates(array) {
  return (new Set(array)).size !== array.length;
}
```

Comment: is there a recommended way how to check if an entry is duplicate in the array or not

Comment: If you want to check for duplicates in an Array, that question has probably been asked on the site already. If the answers to that/those question(s) don't meet your needs then consider asking a new one; but be prepared to explain why the existing answer(s) don't meet your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

`find()` is not a suitable data structure here as it's return type is the element found not the flag(that whether it was found of not). You can use **underscorejs** `_.contains` functions for this.

http://underscorejs.org/#contains